# SQL Server Backup Files

Tags: sql, sql-server, backup

Is the structure of SQL Server database backup BAK file similar to NTBackup BKF file? Is there any reference which can be redirected to understand the difference between NTNAckup and SQL Server Backup (*.bak) files?

Comment: Sounds like it should be on serverfault.com

Answer (score 2):

No, the SQL format and the NT format have absolutely nothing in common.

For an overview of SQL Server backup semantics, see [Backup Overview (SQL Server)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175477.aspx).While the NT backup format is documented at [NT Backup File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd304198(PROT.13).aspx) and there is an API for access, the SQL's backup format is undocumented and the only access API is via the T-SQL BACKUP and RESTORE statements. The SQL backups (format, semantics, API) long predates the existance of NT as an operating system.

Answer (score 1):

According to the answer [How to read the meta data out of SQL Server backup files directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17793006/how-to-read-the-meta-data-out-of-sql-server-backup-files-directly) the .bak file is a Microsoft Tape Format file. 
Here's a [PDF](http://laytongraphics.com/mtf/MTF_100a.PDF) that contains the format.

And here is documentation for NTBackup File https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd305136.aspx