# How to read the meta data out of SQL Server backup files directly?

Tags: sql-server, format, backup, metadata

Generally to get the meta data from SQL Server backup files, we need to use TSQL commands like `restore headeronly` or `restore filelistonly`. However, there are some third party tools can read this information directly from the backup files, like this one http://www.yohz.com/sqlbakreader_details.htm. Since this tool don't have a command line version, which makes it less useful. I want to know whether there are some ways that I can read this data directly.

Thanks.

Comment: If you somehow get the bak file structure from those people, feel free to share it. That structure isn't open to public or otherwise available. Which is ok, because the backup itself is a proprietary feature.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The .bak file is a Microsoft Tape Format file.  Here's a [PDF](http://laytongraphics.com/mtf/MTF_100a.PDF) that contains the format.

Of interest to you will be:

[image]

For a quick dump (if you are on the SQL Server in question that created the backup), you can do select from the [msdb].[dbo].[backup*] tables.

See this [article](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1601/script-to-retrieve-sql-server-database-backup-history-and-no-backups/) for more info.

Comment: Thanks very much Jello. That's a very interesting document and I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be able to use SQL Servers SMO libraries and write your own in .net or Powershell. If you take a look at this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.restore.readbackupheader.aspx there are code samples in VB.Net and Powershell.

Comment: It still requires you to access a SQL Server instance.